# In Rails 3, how can I display the value of the error when using validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display something like:

```
  validates :field, :inclusion => { :in => fields, :message => "is not allowed: {self.field}"}
```

But the self is referring to the class itself rather than the instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want something like

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :size, :in => %w(small medium large),
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid size"
end
```

[Example from the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_inclusion_of)